# Merge rows with same Column A

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, pivot-table

I am new to VBA and from what I have seen it will be the best way to go about doing what I want to do.  I have an excel spreadsheet with Column A being the name of a company and Column B being the state which it is in. Since companies are in multiple states there are repeated company names, I would like to make it so that Column B has a list of the states so that Column A does not repeat.  I know that similar questions have been asked but like I said I am new to this and have never used VBA before so some of the code without an explanation is not all that helpful.

For example I would like to go from:

```
    Company 1 | MI
    Company 1 | IA
    Company 1 | MD
    Company 2 | MI
    Company 2 | OH
```

To this:

```
    Company 1 | MI, IA, MD
    Company 2 | MI, OH
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated or suggestions of ways other than VBA would be appreciated.

Comment: go to the end of the column, then loop through backwards to the top. if the cell.value is the same else the one above it, then erase the value. otherwise, do nothing. you have to be careful with the first line of the sheet, coz there is nothing above it

Comment: I guess I formatted that the wrong way I want the Column B with the same column A in the same cell. Ideally with a line break between them because I would like to merge them into a word document eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put both columns in the ROWS area of a PivotTable and ensure that has no subtotals and is in tabular format.

Comment: I did this but I was sure how to then put it into the word document as just the states.  Like I said in my previous comment ideally I would just be able to use the mail merge in word.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the whole copy and paste. It has been requested that this be done automatically so pretty much they can run a script and it will all be there or they can run the merge mail and it will be there.  I know that what I want can be done in VB I just don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need vba at all. One way to get the results you want is to put the following equation in Column C (assuming Company is in A and States are in B):
"=IF(A2<>A1,A2,"")"
Without the outside quotes. Then just drag the formula to fill to the bottom of the data. Also, if you use this formula, start the data on A2, as the formula will look at the cell above. 
The D column is simply =B2.

The VBA code will follow this logic as well, if you still want to use VBA.

Comment: All this did was eliminate the last instance of the company if there was multiple and sometimes there are more than 2.